# I am failing to maria DB database 10.1 in XAMPP using eclipse oxygen with jdbc driver 5.1

Tags: mysql

I am getting this error:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Incorrect database name ' '
```

after running my code below.

Please help. My database is running in xampp version 3.22. I am using the j connector 5.1

```
    package connect;
    import java.sql.*;
    public class MY_Database {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ ";
    String user = "root";
    String password = "";
    try 
    {
       Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
      Connection con= DriverManager.getConnection(url,user,password);
       Statement stt =  con.createStatement(); 

       //Create and Save db

       stt.execute("Create Database"); 
       stt.execute("Use the test "); 

       //Create out table 
       stt.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXIST people");
       stt.execute("CREATE TABLE people("
               +"id BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,"
               +"fname VARCHAR(25), "
               +"lname VARCHAR (25),"
               +"PRIMARY KEY (id)" 
               +
               " )");
       // ADD SOME ENTRIES 
       stt.execute("INSERT INTO people(fname , lname ) VALUES "+ 
           "('Nathan','Tenderere') ('Praise ''Tenderere') ('Tadiwa 
       ''Machona')");

       // Get people with surname Tenderere
      ResultSet res = stt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM people WHERE lname = 
      'Tenderere'  ");

      while (res.next()) {
          System.out.println(res.getString("fname")+""+ 
       res.getString("lname") );
       }
       }
       catch(Exception e)
       {
       e.printStackTrace();  
       }
       }

       }
```

Answer (score 1):

What is the name of your database? You have your connection string as:

`String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ ";` with a trailing whitespace before the end quote ".

So what you're saying there is that you're trying to connect to a database with name " " which is obviously invalid, remove the trailing whitespace and include your database name in the connection string.